# Imitating message types

Tags: mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am having a configuration where my rover is running mavros 0.13 and my laptop is running mavros 0.15. Therefore there is a difference in namespacing. As I am not able to recompile 0.15 for my rover easily (running out of time for my internship) I was wondering if it is allowed (or do-able) to change the messages of mavros. I think this is needed as I am not able to communicate with my rover as those version differences.

Can I clone the files in `/opt/ros/indigo/include/` so I have a file which defines the message as mavros 0.13? Or should I create a `.msg` file in my own application which generates it for me?

It is for the specific `/mavros/rc/override` message. When starting mavros on my rover, running the application ([ros_erle_teleoperation](https://github.com/erlerobot/ros_erle_teleoperation)) the message type changes to the new 0.15 message type `/mavros_msgs/rc/override` and therefore I seem to not getting the device to work.

Regards,
Martin.

**TL;DR** - Can I duplicate the `mavros/OverrideRCIn` message in the folder `/opt/ros/indigo/include` to make mavros 0.13 on the rover communicate with mavros 0.15 on the laptop?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221125/imitating-message-types/) by [mbeentjes](https://answers.ros.org/users/24675/mbeentjes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should install mavros 0.13 in an overlay on your laptop.  http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0